# How to make pagination table

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

Trying to add pagination into make table.

Max 10 rows at a page.

I do something wrong but, couldn't find it.

But getting this error.

I appreciate any help!

> Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::pagination()

What I am missing here?

**This my controller:**

```
$q = $request->q;
        if ($q !== null && trim($q) !== ""){//here

            $estates = \DB::table('allestates')
                ->paginate(10)
                ->where("building_name","LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
                ->orWhere("address","LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
                ->orWhere("company_name","LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
                ->orWhere("region","LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
                ->orderBy('price')->get();


            if(count($estates) > 0){
                return view("search", compact('estates'))->withQuery($q);
            }

        }

        $estates = array();//here
        return view("search", compact('estates'))->withMessage("No Found!");//here
```

**and my view table:**

```
<table cellspacing='0' class="table table-striped table-class" id= "table-id">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>会社名</th>
        <th>物件名</th>
        <th>住所</th>
        <th>
            <select name="price" class="pricetag">
                <option value="price">販売価格</option>
                <option value="old">旧価格</option>
            </select>
        </th>
        <th class="price-hidden">
            <select name="price" class="pricetag">
                <option value="price">販売価格</option>
                <option value="old">旧価格</option>
            </select>
        </th>
        <th>専有面積</th>
        <th>間取り</th>
        <th>入居時期</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    @foreach($estates as $estate)
        <tr class="even">
            <td>{{str_limit($estate->company_name, $limit = 20)}}</td>
            <td><a href="{{json_decode($estate->link)}}" target="_blank">{{str_limit($estate->building_name, $limit = 20)}}</a><br/></td>
            <td>{{str_limit($estate->address, $limit = 22)}}</td>

            <td>{{str_limit($estate->price, $limit = 20)}}</td>
            <td class="price-hidden">{{$estate->old_price}}</td>

            <td>{{str_limit($estate->extend, $limit = 20)}}</td>
            <td>{{str_limit($estate->rooms, $limit = 20)}}</td>
            <td>{{str_limit($estate->entry, $limit = 20)}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
{{ $estate->links() }}
```

Thank you for helping me out!

Comment: Refer below link for pagination : https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/pagination

Answer (score 1):

I think pagination should follow where condition.
Try replace ->get() with ->paginate(10).

Comment: I make it out. thanks but numbers are not showing on the page I tried this  `{{ $estate->links() }}`

Comment: It should be $ estates

Comment: thanks mate, sorry for typo. now links are coming but all of'em dead giving me this. `Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message`

Comment: You should check the route, the method should be " get".

Answer (score 0):

you can use paginate(10) or simplepaginate(10)

And inside the loop in view you must whrite

```
@foreach($estates->all() as $estate)
```

and replace  {{ $estate->links() }} to {{ $estates->links() }}